# Is a population parameter really a fixed quantity?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference, population, parameterization

This might be a simple issue.

I consistently come across internet sources that say that a population parameter is "fixed" and cannot change. However, if we define, for example, our parameter to be the average age of living UK citizens, it could currently be, for example, 40.21292... years, which interestingly could easily be obtained because there is a registry (unlike parameters from other less-well-defined populations). However, the number of people that have been born and died before our next measurement is unlikely to be equal and thus the average age might, for example, be 40.10432 instead. In effect, our population parameter has changed. Could somebody explain that?

Comment: You are confusing parameter with estimate. When doing frequentist statistical inference the parameter has a fixed value that you try to estimate. Bayesian inference treats the parameter as random to quantify the uncertainty in it & combines prior uncertainty with data to determine the uncertainty after obtaining the data. So Bayesian inference doesn't treat the parameter as fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A population parameter is a fixed value, however, a population may not be fixed - if the population changes, so may the parameter that describes it. Given some population of individuals, we typically try to estimate some parameter by taking a sample of that population. At any point in time, we have some fixed, mostly unseen population that we're trying to describe with our observed sample. In some cases, we have an implicit assumption that a population is invariant over time, which would allow us to treat multiple samplings as samples of the same population. This may not be true if the population changes over time - if you want to determine the mean height of UK citizens, you'd almost certainly get different answers if you drew your sample from the population 300 years ago, or the population today. However, that doesn't indicate that there isn't a true "mean height" that exists at both points in time - that mean height is a fixed value which we try to approximate with sampling.

Answer (score 1):

The population described here represents a distribution, and the one you have as UK population is a sample from it, which is why the parameter changes while for the population it is fixed.

In this sense, although you use the entire UK population to estimate the average age of living, it'll only represent an *estimate* of the true *unseen* population average age of living, which is the distribution that the current UK *population* is sampled from.

But, I agree with the comments and other answer by @NuclearWang that if the statistical population is defined as the UK population, then when it changes, so must the parameter.

Comment: Finite populations are easily defined in principle and identified in practice. Here is one: a deck of 52 cards, which can be sampled again and again. Also, the wording that the population is a sample doesn't help.

Comment: The UK census population *is* the population in a statistical sense. It's not a sampling of some unseen distribution, since it already contains every possible sample. If you know the age of every single living person in the UK, you're not limited to *estimating*  mean age - you can compute it directly with absolute certainty. Or is the argument here that the database figures are incomplete, since they likely don't really capture *everyone* in the UK?

Comment: @NuclearWang Actually, I must agree with you both. But, what I had in mind is that the people in UK are drawn from a distribution $f_X(x)$ that represents the *underlying* population (i.e. all the people in UK that are currently living, had lived and will be living) and we(they)'re all samples from it, no matter how large it is.

Comment: @gunes I think that in a way comes back to the idea of time-invariance that the OP alluded to. I'd expect "average age of living individuals" to change significantly over the course of centuries, and all we can really get with a sample from today is an estimate that describes today's population. I suppose there would be some true distribution of ages over all times that would represent an unchanging population, but using today's census population as a sample of that all-time population (both past and present) would be highly biased.